# Figuring out different CoNLL format

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to generate a conll file from Stanford Core NLP, which then can be used as an input to Semafor (as semafor accepts conll file only).

The generated file looks like this:

```
1   My  my  PRP$    O   2   nmod:poss
2   kitchen kitchen NN  O   5   nsubj
3   no  no  RB  O   4   neg
4   longer  longer  RB  O   5   advmod
5   smells  smell   VBZ O   0   ROOT
6   .   .   .   O   5   punct
```

When I use this file, the Semafor server returns illegalArgument exception since the format is slightly different. Their example conll file looks like this:

```
1   My  _   PRP$    PRP$    _   2   NMOD    _   _
2   kitchen _   NN  NN  _   5   SBJ _   _
3   no  _   RB  RB  _   5   ADV _   _
4   longer  _   RB  RB  _   3   AMOD    _   _
5   smells  _   VBZ VBZ _   0   ROOT    _   _
6   .   _   .   .   _   5   P   _   _
```

It seems that I can control the output by defining the keys. The default keys are ID, FORM, LEMMA,POSTAG,NER, HEAD, DEPREL. However, I don't know the keys for the example conll file provided by Semafor. Please guide me how I might convert the generated file format into Semafor example file format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Semafor can generate its own conll file in the format that it needs. We use Stanford Core NLP just to split a document into sentences per line, and then use Semafor itself to generate the conll file.